# Using popen to compile external program

Tags: c, linux, popen

I am creating an online judge. For this I am writing a CGI c script, that takes the program content, and compiles the program.

Here is my function to compile an external c program.

```
char *compile_program(char *compile_script){
printf("%s\n", compile_script);
compile_script = "gcc /var/www/FilebCamFz.c -o /var/www/FilebCamFz";
FILE *output_file;
output_file = popen(compile_script, "w");

char *output, *full_output, *full_error;
output = malloc(50000);
full_output = malloc(50000);
full_error = malloc(50000);

setbuf(stderr, full_error);
setbuf(stdout, full_output);

if(output_file == NULL){
    // Some error
    fprintf(stderr, "Compilation failed. Try again.\n");
    return full_error;
}
else{
    // If command executed successfully
    while (fgets(output, 5000000, output_file) != NULL){
       strcat(full_output, output);
    }

    if (pclose (output_file) == 0){
        return full_output;
    }
    else
        fprintf (stderr, "Could not run more or other error.\n");
        return full_error;
}

//return EXIT_SUCCESS; }
```

When calling the function with `ls`, `free -m` command, the output is as expected.

But when running commands like `python -v`, etc an empty output is obtained.

While on running commands like `gcc /var/www/FilebCamFz.c -o /var/www/FilebCamFz`, I'm getting a stderr on `pclose()`.

So my question is, what's the reason for this unusual behavior of popen. 
And how can I compile an external program (c, c++, python, java, etc) via `popen()`

Comment: "a stderr on pclose()"? Huh? `stderr` is a file descriptor, not an error number.

Comment: You also seem to be confused about what `setbuf` does.

Comment: I should also point out that this seems naïve and potentially very vulnerable. I would read about [some of the lengths that codepad.org goes to](http://codepad.org/about) when compiling and executing others’ code.

Comment: So whats the best way to execute such commands. I have already taken care of ignoring restricted calls and system resources.

Comment: What's wrong with using `fork()` and `exec()`? Why make things difficult for yourself by using `popen()`?

Comment: You should use `fread` for binary data instead of `fgets` or your read will terminate every time `0xa` (e.g. the `'\n'` char) is encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally solved it by using docker containers.